# mobile trouble with viewport settings

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport

I'm developing a mobile site for the first time and i'm trying to create a responsive design.

So far i'm having a lot of trouble with the viewstate settings. Mostly on Android but also some on iPhone.

I'm using these settings:

And i'm also using this in my CSS (just to be sure):
    @-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }
    @-o-viewport { width: device-width; }
    @viewport { width: device-width; }

It works perfect most of the time on my iPhone. But sometimes when i change to landscape and then back to normal, the resolution of the page gets smaller. And sometimes it stays the same (as it should).

On the Android phone it works perfectly both in landscape and normal modes. Here my problem is, that sometimes when i refresh the page, it seems like the mobile doesn't read the viewport settings at all. It just looks like a normal webpage that isn't optimized for mobile.

Anyone have an idea about what i'm doing wrong here?

*EDIT*

i also tried to add the meta viewport tags (i don't know why my code doesn't show up in this post, but that doesn't Work either).

Comment: you can refer this question [link][1]  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147859/responsive-navigation-with-images

Comment: I don't wanna set specific styles for each resolution right now. I just want each mobile device to view the site in the right size and not zoomed out like it does by standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by simplifying and rechecking your code.

In the head of your page make sure you have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

If there are additional viewport tags, remove them for now.

For the media queries in your CSS use

```
@media (max-width: 767px){     /* adjust viewport width as req'd */

.selector{ ... }

}
```

and remove the the other @ tags you've used (eg @-ms-viewport)

Good luck!